# KSnapshot - Upload to Imgur account

Tags: kde, ksnapshot

I use KSnapshot on KDE, it uploads to Imgur (as anonymous) but I want to upload it to Imgur in my account. How to make this happen?

**I want to upload my screenshots with KSnapshot directly to Imgur using my Imgur-pro-account** (see screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHzle.png)

Comment: slightly disappointed the screenshot can't be of itself being uploaded :P

Comment: I would love to see an answer to this